# Building R package on win32: Unable to load shared object (.dll)

Tags: c++, r, dll, 32bit-64bit, r-package

I'm updating an [R package](https://github.com/ms609/TreeTools) that I last released (with no problems) on R3.6.  I've since updated to R 4.0.0 and Rtools 40.

The package builds and runs successfully on 64-bit R.  But I see that on win builder, the package's testthat tests fail on win32 (but not win64).

To diagnose the failure, I'm building the package on my 64-bit Windows 10 machine, using a 32-bit version of R and `devtools::install(args= "--no-multiarch")`.
I've edited the `PATH` environment variable, replacing:

- C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\x64 *with* C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\i386
- C:\rtools40\mingw64\bin *with* C:\rtools40\mingw32\bin (and I've also tried C:\rtools40\clang32\bin)

The install process is indeed looking to mingw**32** for the g++ and gcc executables.  Installation is successful, with no warnings or errors.

However, when I attempt to load the package with `devtools::load_all()`, I see:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/path/to/PACKAGENAME/src/PACKAGENAME.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

If I instead run `library('PACKAGENAME')`, then run tests, the R GUI freezes and exits silently -- paralleling the failure on win builder.

I'm struggling to diagnose why a DLL that works perfectly on 64-bit won't work on a 32-bit architecture.  The only substantive [change](https://github.com/ms609/TreeTools/compare/v0.1.4...master) I've made to the C++ code is to replace some `int`s with `typedef int16_t xint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been the existence of 64-bit dlls in the package's source folder (as insinuated by the error message), created by 'devtools'.

Once these files were deleted `load_all` would happily re-create them using the 32-bit compilers.